# Verify if directories and files are allowed to be renamed

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, prism

For my application, I allow the users to be able to rename the project, this would mean I need to rename the directory and the files on disk. The issue is that if the directory is opened by the user. I will get the error "*Access to the path '...' is denied.*", but at this point I have already renamed couple of files.

My question is if there is a way to verify if the directory or the files can be renamed without any issues before I begin to make the changes.

Here's a snippet of my code that I have so far:

```
Try

    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(WorkingDirectory)

    ' Verify if the old directory path exists on the disk, if so rename it using the new directory name.

    If IO.Directory.Exists(oldDirectoryPath) Then

        ' Delete old project file
        If IO.File.Exists(oldFilePath) Then
            IO.File.Delete(oldFilePath)
        End If

        ' Rename all files in subdirec with new name
        If IO.Directory.Exists(oldSubDirectory) Then
            For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(oldSubDirectory,
                                                         $"*_{oldName}.*",
                                                         IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)   
                FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile(file, newFileName)   
            Next
        End If

       FileIO.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(oldDirectoryPath, directory.Name)

    End If
Catch ex As IO.IOException
' Show error message to user
End Try
```

Comment: why not just use `try/catch`?

Comment: You have to use try/catch. The time between verifying and changing, an other process can remove access. Put a try/catch only on RenameFile with the proper exception. Your folder could even be removed by the time you check if it's there and then try to rename it.

Comment: I do have a try/catch for the method, but if there is an error after renaming couple of files, then I'm stuck in the middle.

Comment: Add a rollback in your Catch. If newName Then oldName.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't leave a comment. But I think this is a very interesting question.
But I was wondering how about first renaming the directory and then the files. if any file in that directory is open you can't rename the directory hence you haven't renamed any file either. Just a thought!